# What is the .Net tracing facility? where can I start reading about it?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, trace

Can I use tracing instead of my manual logging mechanism?
Please recommend good references and advices.

Comment: try googling for ".net tracing"

Comment: I think this is a valid question, and if we can combine good references/advices here it'll better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reasonable introduction to the topic: [Tracing in .NET and Implementing Your Own Trace Listeners](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/article.php/c19405/Tracing-in-NET-and-Implementing-Your-Own-Trace-Listeners.htm)

Answer (score 0):

See this post [Tracing versus Logging and how does log4net fit in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172372/tracing-versus-logging-and-how-does-log4net-fit-in)